# What did the Predator see that made him spare this character?

Tags: alien-vs.-predator

In *Alien vs. Predator (2004)*, in one scene the Predator is about to kill

> Weyland

but it uses its x-ray vision to look inside him and, seeing something, decides not to kill him.

Can anybody tell me why the Predator didn't kill him and what it found with the x-ray?

---

Note: the idea for this question came from http://www.moviemistakes.com/film4357/questions

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Predator (Scar as he is called in Alien vs Predator) saw cancer in [Charles Weyland's](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Bishop_Weyland) lungs.

[Scar](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Scar) considered Weyland unworthy prey.  He only killed Weyland after being provoked by him.

> He implored the others to leave him behind and prepared to face the
>   pursuing Scar alone, hoping to buy the others time to escape. However,
>   the Predator refrained from killing him when it detected that he was
>   dying of cancer, evidently considering him unworthy prey. Enraged by
>   this turn of events, Weyland attacked Scar using a flamethrower
>   improvised from his medicinal inhaler and a flare, causing the
>   Predator to turn and impale Weyland on its Wristblades, killing him
>   before carelessly throwing his body aside.

Scar was a Yautja.  The Yautja have a very strict honor [code](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Yautja_Honor_Code).

> **Hunting Worthy Game:** When hunting, the hunter must be sure that his
>   prey is considered game, and lawful to kill. Sometimes the hunter will
>   equal the odds (not using a Plasmacaster or some other weapon). Worthy
>   game must fill the following criteria: Can defend itself and/or is
>   able to kill the hunter himself, of age (killing children and the
>   elderly is considered the height of bad manners), not linked to other
>   lives (so that removing the prey will not doom another, e.g. pregnant
>   women), and not weakened by diseases.

Comment: The last part of that code (re. pregnant women) we saw in [Predator 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_2) *"The Predator prepares to kill Cantrell but releases her after a quick visual scan of her body reveals that she is pregnant."*

Comment: Interesting how the predators have a code of honor. It's kind of interesting that some of the deadliest killers have a code of honor.  it's like the samurai of Japan... You wouldn't want to mess with them, but they have a very strict honor code.

Comment: @XaolingBao Kind of like the mafia, too.  They will go and shoot you in the back of the head on the way to Church service ;)  They have a strict honor code as well.

Comment: @steelerfan I'd say "From the church service". They are not monsters... ;)

Comment: @Yasskier - [Yes they are](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/myths-about-the-mafia-exposed-as-three-year-old-is-brutally-murdered-9208753.html).

Answer (score 9):

Weyland had lung cancer, specifically [bronchogenic carcinoma](http://www.meddean.luc.edu/lumen/meded/medicine/pulmonar/pathms/path19.htm) <sub><sup>(warning, link has **graphic images**)</sup></sub>

The [screenplay](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/AVP-FinalProduction.RTF) is pretty blunt. He doesn't forebear from killing Weyland because it would be *dis*honourable (in the same way that killing a pregnant woman would be shameful), it's because killing him wouldn't be worthy of his time.

> [**Below:**  Human and Predator face off.  Weyland draws himself up to
>   his full height.  He's going out with a fight.  Weyland swings at
>   Scar.  Scar catches the ice axe and crumples it in his fist.]
>
> [**PREDATOR VISION:**  Scar sees Weyland in his distinctive heat
>   signature vision.  Like an MRI, the Predator vision scans over
>   Weyland's wrecked body, a body riddled with disease.  Like stars in
>   the sky, the tumors are everywhere. The cancer has destroyed Weyland.]
>
> [Scar turns away from Weyland and walks up the stairs.  **To Scar, he's
>   nothing but a sick animal.  Weyland is not worthy of the hunt.**]
>
> <sub><sup>[AVP Final Production Screenplay](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/AVP-FinalProduction.RTF)</sup></sub>

---

The novelisation goes into a little more detail.

> Four years earlier, Weyland had told Max Stafford that, given forty
>   more years on earth, the scientific research his company funded would
>   enable Weyland Industries to open a branch in a moon base on the Sea
>   of Tranquility. But that was before he’d been diagnosed with advanced
>   bronchogenic carcinoma. Now, because of the cancer that was eating
>   away his lungs, Charles Weyland no longer had forty more years. If he
>   was lucky, he might have forty more days.
>
> <sup><sub>[Alien vs. Predator - Official Novelisation](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_(novel))</sub></sup>

When it "scanned" him, the Predator evidently detected his illness and refused to attack him.

> The creature turned and stared down at Weyland. As blank eyes on the Predator’s faceplate glowed with crimson fire, the human felt a strange warmth inside his chest. Reaching out, the Predator clutched Weyland’s shoulders, held him fast and examined him from head to toe.
>   Then, snorting contemptuously, the creature pushed Weyland aside and turned his back on him.
>   **Weyland understood what that meant. Somehow the Predator could sense his frailty and did not regard him as a threat** — in fact, Weyland was sure that, to this monster, he was nothing more than a sick, helpless animal!
>
> <sup><sub>[Alien vs. Predator - Official Novelisation](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_(novel))</sub></sup>